# Wordpress posts loop pagination - first page return 125 posts instead of 10 and the rest return 10

Tags: posts, loop, pagination

I'm trying to show 10 posts per page with pagination on WordPress and the first page return 125 posts instead of 10 and the rest of the pages return 10 posts as requested, please assist :)

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$output = array();
global $post;
$args = array('nopaging' => false, 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post_type' => 'post', 'order'=> 'DES', 'orderby' => 'date');
$postslist = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $postslist->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $postslist->have_posts() ) : $postslist->the_post(); 

    array_push($output, array("timestamp" => get_the_date('U'),"img_url" => get_the_post_thumbnail_url(), "title" => get_the_title(), "text" => get_the_content()));
         endwhile;  

        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
```

Comment: I think the problem is pagination part. For example, there are 136 items, the pagination section on first page shows 1 and 2, but 2nd page shows 1,2,3,...13. So I think you need to implement your own pagination code.

Comment: do you have any 'sticky' posts? try to explicitely exclude them from the query.

Comment: @Michael WOW man you are the king! thanks for the answer, this was the issue it seems. thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sticky posts was the problem, Thanks to @Michael answer, I have excluded the sticky_posts from the query

```
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
```